# How to always start an App from the main activity, even after being closed using the home button from sync settings

Tags: android

The scenario:
My app turns toggles the wifi state when a button is pressed and then exits the app. If background data is enabled when the wifi is being disabled, then the app allows the user to disable the bg data by starting the Sync Settings activity
    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SYNC_SETTINGS));
This works great except that when the user returns to the home screen from the sync settings activity by pressing the home button, the app will still show the sync settings when reopened, and not the main activity.

What can I do so that anytime my app is opened it starts on the main activity, no matter how or where it was closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the no history flag. What you want is to start all the activity with the No history flag. So when the APP is closed and is returning from home button again, all the activities (except for the main one) are destroyed

So let's say your main activity want to start activity A

```
Class ourClass = Class.forName("ActivityA");    
Intent ourIntent = new Intent(this, ourClass);  
ourIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);//This is the flag I am talking about
startActivity(ourIntent);
```

Comment: Intent intent  = new Intent(this, WifiShortcutActivity.class);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
  
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SYNC_SETTINGS));  something like this?

Comment: When u start an activity dont create new intent otherwise u will lose the older one with the flag . You should use the same intent

Comment: Thanks used this: Intent intent  = new Intent("android.settings.SYNC_SETTINGS");
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);  
  startActivity(intent); and it worked

Answer (score -1):

In every activity except the main add->

```
     @Override
 public void onPause() {
         finish();
     super.onPause();

 }
```

now when your app is paused on any activity, it will finish it. This also means that when going from one activity to the next you will not be able to hit the back button to go back one, it will always take you to main.